# Use Recurrence Table with Generating Function

Tags: recursion, difference-equations

I tried to use Generating Function to solve Fibonacci series using following function.

Input:

```
GeneratingFunction[RSolve[{f[n + 2] == f[n + 1] + f[n], f[0] == 0,
f[1] == 1}, f[n], n], n, x]
```

Output:

```
{{GeneratingFunction[f[n], n, x] -> -(x/(-1 + x + x^2))}}
```

I want to plot this function using graph for a particular range, like as follows:

Input:

```
RecurrenceTable[{f[n + 2] == f[n + 1] + f[n], f[0] == 0, f[1] == 1}, f, {n, 0, 10}]
```

Output:

```
{0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55}
```

Can I get a list of values using Generating function for recurrence relation to plot it on a graph. This is just an example to understand my problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
g = GeneratingFunction[Fibonacci@n, n, x]
CoefficientList[Series[g, {x, 0, 10}], x]

(* {0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55} *)
```